# GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging - duplicate message

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am trying to use Galasoft Messaging, and seem to be encountering an interesting behaviour in the User Control receiving the message. The messaging seems to happen fine, but the method that is invoked when a message is received in the User Control viewmodel seems to execute twice. Using console output (Console.WriteLine) to verify, it appears the message is only sent once by the main window. On the user control side, the console output always seems to display the message twice... Is it possible that there is 2 instances of the view model being instantiated?
The Main Window, that broadcasts the message is as follows:

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using ETGTools;
using System.Security.Principal;

using ETG.Interfaces;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

using ETGTools.Views;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;

namespace MessengerDemo.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string gcETGVersion = "v123";
        public int iii = 0;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadTabs();
            winCon.Title = winCon.Title + " (assembly666)";
            tbxUser.Text = "schin";
        }

        private void LoadTabs()
        {
            var dllsPath = new List<string> {
                @"C:\workspaceVS\ETGTools\trunk\Tools\bin\Debug\ETGTools.dll"
            };

            foreach (var dllPath in dllsPath)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
                var typeName = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                                where type.GetInterface("ETG.Interfaces.ITab") != null
                                select type.FullName).SingleOrDefault();

                var uc = assembly.CreateInstance(typeName, true);
                var tab = (ITab)uc;
                tab.Init();

                RadTabItem rTi = new RadTabItem();
                rTi.Header = tab.description;
                Grid gRd = new Grid();
                gRd.Children.Add((UserControl)uc);
                rTi.Content = gRd;
                tabControl.Items.Add(rTi);
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send<string>(tbxOrd.Text, "String_ToHelpMatchTheMsg");
            iii++;
            Console.WriteLine("mainwindow loop count: " + iii);
        }
    }
}
```

Main XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:ETGTools;assembly=ETGTools"
        xmlns:UCV="clr-namespace:ETGTools.Views;assembly=ETGTools"
        xmlns:UCVM="clr-namespace:ETGTools.ViewModels;assembly=ETGTools"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="MessengerDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns:command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
        x:Name="winCon" Title="MessengerDemo" Height="800" Width="1100" Background="LightBlue" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="listViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        </Style>
            <Style x:Key="steviesRadListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="telerik:RadListBoxItem">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border >
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{Binding oops}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Margin="93,39,16,37" BorderBrush="SlateBlue" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid Name="grdApps" ShowGridLines="True">
            <telerik:Label Content="Productivity Gauge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="272,-33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.444,-0.158" Width="112" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            <telerik:Label x:Name="lblTrend" Content="trending" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="468,-33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.444,-0.158" Width="66" FontStyle="Italic" ToolTip="tap to refresh!">
                <telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
                    <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding CountCommand}" EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown"
RaiseOnHandledEvents="True" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
            </telerik:Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxOrds" Background="{Binding Xaml1.Color1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="384,-37,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Xaml1.Text1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" ToolTip="" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <Label Content="Buyer/Owner" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbxBName" Text="{Binding Order1.BName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label Content="Seller" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbxSName" Text="{Binding Order1.SName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label Content="Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox Name="tbxAddr" Text="{Binding Order1.Addr}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="130,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Label Content="Order #" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="735,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbxUser" Text="{Binding Order1.FUser, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="399,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Xaml1.Visibility1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="tbxOrd" Text="{Binding Order1.Escrow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="789,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135"/>
            <TextBox Name="test" Text="{Binding Order1.Status, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="789,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-0.135" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <Button Content="GO" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="924,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <Button  Content="Help!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="924,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.75"/>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="601" Margin="21,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="931">
                    <telerik:RadTabControl Name="tabControl" Margin="10">
                    <telerik:RadTabItem Header="Delivery" Height="30" Width="60" Visibility="{Binding Xaml1.Visibility1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="601" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="931" Visibility="{Binding Xaml1.Visibility1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <UCV:DeliveryUC UCESI="{Binding Path=ESIs, Mode=TwoWay}"  UC1="{Binding DataContext.ContainerData, ElementName=winCon, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </telerik:RadTabItem>
                </telerik:RadTabControl>
        </Grid>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="680" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" Margin="-87,-4,0,0">
                <Grid Name="grdL20" Margin="-83,-2,83,2" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="600*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="69*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="83,1,-83,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Source="/MessengerDemo;component/images/charlieC.png"/>
                    <Label BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue" Content="Last 20 Files" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,105,-83,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80"/>
                    <telerik:RadListBox x:Name="rlbLast20" ItemsSource="{Binding ULast}" DisplayMemberPath="Last20"
                                        Visibility="{Binding Xaml1.Visibility1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource steviesRadListBoxItemStyle}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,135,-83,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="400" Background="Salmon" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" MaxHeight="400">
                        <telerik:RadListBox.BindingGroup>
                            <BindingGroup/>
                        </telerik:RadListBox.BindingGroup>
                        <telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
                            <telerik:EventBinding Command="{Binding CustomCommand}" EventName="MouseDoubleClick"
RaiseOnHandledEvents="True" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                        </telerik:EventToCommandBehavior.EventBindings>
                    </telerik:RadListBox>
                    <CheckBox Name="cbxCook" Content="cookies" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97,35,-69,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Xaml1.Checked1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

User Control (view model) registered for message:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;

namespace ETGTools.ViewModels
{
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using ETGTools.Views;
    using ETGTools.Models;
    using ETGTools.Commands;

    public class DisclosureControlViewModel : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int iii = 0;
        private int jjj = 0;

        private string _viewModelStringProperty;
        public string ViewModelStringProperty
        {
            get { return _viewModelStringProperty; }
            set
            {
                _viewModelStringProperty = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ViewModelStringProperty"));
                }
            }
        }

        public DisclosureControlViewModel()
        {
            _DiscCntl = new DiscCntl();
            _Xaml1 = new Xaml1();
            Xaml1.Focusable1 = true;
            Xaml1.Enabled1 = false;
            _UserProfile = new UserProfile();
            UserProfile.Pwd = UC1+"please";
            UserProfile.User = "what: " + ViewModelStringProperty;

            GoCommand = new GoCommand(this);

            Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "String_ToHelpMatchTheMsg", executeThisFunction);
            jjj++;
        }

        private void executeThisFunction(string strMsg)
        {
            //your code would go here to run upon receiving the message
            // The following line will display: "Dummy text message" 
            //MessageBox.Show("msg passed: " + strMsg);
            iii++;
            Console.WriteLine("in UC jjj:"+jjj.ToString()+", iii:"+iii.ToString()+", msg passed: " + strMsg);
            return;
        }
        private string _uC1;
        public string UC1
        {
            get { return _uC1; }
            set
            {
                _uC1 = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UC1"));
                }
            }
        }

        private UserProfile _UserProfile;
        public UserProfile UserProfile
        {
            get
            {
                return _UserProfile;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private ETGTools.Models.Xaml1 _Xaml1;
        public ETGTools.Models.Xaml1 Xaml1
        {
            get
            {
                return _Xaml1;
            }
        }

        private DiscCntl _DiscCntl;
        public DiscCntl DiscCntl
        {
            get
            {
                return _DiscCntl;
            }
        }
        public void DoGo()
        {
            Xaml1.Focusable1 = false;
            Xaml1.Enabled1 = true;
        }
        public bool CanGo
        {
            get
            {
                if (DiscCntl == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DiscCntl.Id);
            }
        }
        public ICommand GoCommand
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that you have two instances of the VM subscribed to receive the message.

That is very easy to verify though. In the VM constructor generate a unique variable (GUID for example) and in the method receiving the message check the value of that variable. If they do not match you have two instances receiving the message and need to figure out why that happens in your code.

Also, sometimes a VM remains in memory when the view is closed, while it's waiting to be garbage collected, and continues to receive messages so make sure you unsubscribe from receiving the messages in your VM whenever your view is closed...